# javascript - passing multiple values

Tags: javascript

I have the following function call

```
    setVal("' + key + ',' + addressid + '")
```

Note how I am trying to pass in 2 values, key and address id.

I have the actual function as below:

```
    function setVal(key, addressid) {

    }
```

when I check the value of key in the SetVal function, I get key = the value of hcpkey + ',' + addressid.

The value of addressid is undefined although it does have a value. Am I doing something wronge in how I am passing the value?

Comment: Why on earth would you write that?

Comment: You're passing in only 1 parameter, a string delimited by your double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all those quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You call the function with one big string: `"' + key + ',' + addressid + '")`

You should call it like this:

```
setVal("First Value", "Second Value");
```

If those are variables, leave the quotes:

```
setVal(key, addressid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a single argument; a string with the value `' + key + ',' + addressid + '`

Unless you're trying to do something I've not picked up on, you just want this:

```
setVal(key, addressid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply call your function like this:

```
setVal(key, addressid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use quotes where you don't need them:

```
setVal(key, addressid);
```

You want variables (or rather their values) and not the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to pass them separately:

```
setVal(key, addressid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function like this:

```
setVal(key, addressid);
```